# Is it possible to get Installs and Crashes data from App Store Connect API?

Tags: node.js, web, analytics, app-store-connect

I'm trying to get installs/crashes data filtered by month from App Store.
Seems like official App Store Connect API does not provide such functionality.

I've already tried [itunesconnect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/itunesconnect), and [iTunesConnectAnalytics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/itunesconnectanalytics) but it also doesnt work well.

Any ideas or suggestion how can i achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The (official) App Store Connect API currently does not provide these information. At the time of this writing it supports:

- TestFlight. Manage beta builds of your app, testers, and groups.
- Users and Access. Send invitations for users to join your team. Adjust their level of access or remove users.
- Provisioning. Manage bundle IDs, capabilities, signing certificates, devices, and provisioning profiles.
- Reporting. Download sales and financial reports.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi

`spaceship` (which is a `ruby` framework and powers `fastlane`) gives some options to access the private App Store Connect API and currently exposed some App Store Analytics: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/spaceship/lib/spaceship/tunes/app_analytics.rb

I'm sure you can extend it as well with additional metrics from there.